# Pass a widget in argument of a SLOT

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, button, signals-slots

Here's what I want to do:
I have a QLineEdit and a QPushButton. When I push the button I want to retrieve the text of the QLineEdit and do stuff with it. Unfortunately, I am struggling to do it because I'm kind of a newbie with Qt.

My mainwindow.cpp (simplified):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QLineEdit *textInput = new QLineEdit();
    QPushButton *awesomeButton = new QPushButton();

    retrieveButton->setText("Click me");

    connect(awesomeButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(awesomeFunction(QLineEdit)));

}

void MainWindow::awesomeFunction(QLineEdit myQLineEdit) {
    QString exploitedText = myQLineEdit.text();
    //DO STUFF
}
```

My mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void awesomeFunction(QLineEdit myQLineEdit);

private:
    QPushButton *awesomeButton;
    QLineEdit *textInput;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif
```

There's nothing interesting in `main.cpp`. I am missing something but I don't know what. When I  use this without any parameters to my function, it works fine. But when I try to pass a Widget in parameter it doesn't work. The documentation is well done but I can manage to find what I need over the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code shown.  Firstly `QObject`, and by implication anything that inherits from it, is non-copyable so you can't pass a `QLineEdit` by value: you need to pass by reference/pointer.

Secondly the line...

```
connect(awesomeButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(awesomeFunction(QLineEdit)));
```

should issue a runtime warning on the console because the slot expects an argument -- `QLineEdit` -- but the `QPushButton::released` signal doesn't provide one.

Assuming the `QLineEdit` you're interested in is `textInput` then you can make use of the new Qt5 signal/slot syntax and a `lambda`.  So change the `awesomeButton` signature to...

```
void awesomeFunction(QLineEdit *myQLineEdit);
```

and then connect to the signal with (untested)...

```
connect(awesomeButton, &QPushButton::released, this,
        [this, textInput]()
          {
            awesomeFunction(textInput);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `QPushButton::clicked()` signal. Have a look at this signal documentation, like `release()`, it doesn't have parameters. Slot in Qt should be with the same signature as signal. These signals doesn't send any `QLineEdit's`.

Use:

```
void MainWindow::awesomeFunction() {
    QString exploitedText = textInput->text();
    //DO STUFF
}
```